# Illustrator: editing technical artwork imported from PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I have copied a technical drawing from PDF in AI and I need to add more details. However there is a box around the whole drawing which does not let me reach the individual elements of the artwork. How do I get rid of the box and access the elements of the drawing?

Answer (score 3):

The main box is probably a clipping mask. Select it and select Object-->Clipping Mask-->Release.

You may also need to ungroup objects. Multiple times.